# Computing $P(\limsup S_n=\infty)$ and $P(\liminf S_n=-\infty)$ for a random walk

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk

Let $X_i$ be i.i.d. non-degenerate random variables with $EX_i=0$, and consider the random walk $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.

If $X_i$ was a simple random walk (i.e., $P(X_i = -1) = 1/2 = P(X_i = 1)$), I am able to show that $$P(\limsup S_n = \infty) = 1 = P(\liminf S_n = -\infty).$$

In my proof of the above statement, I do so by first showing that infinitely often the random walk must take $M$ consecutive positive steps infinitely often, for all $M\in\mathbb{N}$, with probability $1$. Similarly, one can show that the random walk must take $M$ consecutive negative steps infinitely often with probability $1$. (I am also aware that there are other questions on this site that address the above statement.)

However, my question is can this be generalized beyond this simple case of a simple random walk for $X_i$ following an arbitrary, non degenerate distribution with mean $0$? And if so, how does one go about a proof? In the case of the simple random walk we had a nice clean characterization of the distribution of the $X_i$, but in a generalized version we do not. Thanks!

Comment: The probabilities are both equal to 1. When variance is finite this follows immediately from the Law of Iterated Logarithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm. The result is true in general but I don't recall the proof at this moment.

Comment: FYI, the fact "that infinitely often the random walk must take M consecutive positive steps infinitely often, for all M∈ℕ, with probability 1" does not imply that the limsup is + infinity almost surely.

Comment: @Did - I know. I did not mean to say that this statement implies the result. It was an intermediate step I showed in the simple Bernoulli case, and put it there in case similar sorts of arguments could be used more generally. But, perhaps, the comment was unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probabilities are both equal to $1$ for any non-trivial random walk $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ satisfying $\mathbb{E}(X_i)=0$; this is a direct consequence of a statement by Chung-Fuchs:

> Let $(X_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of non-trivial iid $\mathbb{R}$-valued random variables, and denote by $S_n := \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ the associated random walk. Then the following statements hold true.
>
> - $\mathbb{E}X_1>0 \iff \lim_{n \to \infty} S_n = \infty$ almost surely
> - $\mathbb{E}X_1<0 \iff \lim_{n \to \infty} S_n = -\infty$ almost surely
> - $\mathbb{E}X_1 = 0 \iff - \infty = \liminf_{n \to \infty} S_n < \limsup_{n \to \infty} S_n = \infty$ almost surely.

The proof is relatively easy if the steps $X_i$ are bounded (i.e. $\mathbb{P}(X_1 \leq K)=1$ for some $K>0$); for general random variables $X_i$ the proof is more involved.

Comment: Do you have a reference for a proof of this theorem? Or a least simple proof for the bounded case where $P(X_1\le K)=1$? Appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: @Satana You can find the statement, for instance, in a book by Alsmeyer (http://www.uni-muenster.de/Stochastik/alsmeyer/Skripten/rt_book.pdf); it's Theorem 2.2.9.

Comment: {\c{C}}{\i}nlar also showed it in \href{https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-0-387-87859-1.pdf}{p.88 Example 5.19}.