# Prove sum of i.i.d. random variables becomes arbitrarily large

Tags: probability

I have an unknown continuous distribution, density function $f_X$, with the following properties:

- Zero mean
- Symmetric around the mean
- For all $a,b : 0 \leq a < b$ we have $f_X(a) > f_X(b)$

I'm looking at sums of IID draws from this distribution $Y_n = \sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ and would like to show that such sums get arbitrarily large with probability 1. Formally, I guess it would be that for all $t > 0$
$$\lim_{n=1}^{\infty}P\left(\bigvee_{k=1}^n|Y_k| > t\right) = 1$$
My first thought is to lower bound the disjunction by
$$P\left(\bigvee_{k=1}^n|Y_k| > t\right) > P\left(|Y_n| > t\right)$$
hoping that would be enough. Intuitively it feels correct, as the variance becomes unbounded. That is, if the variance of $f_X$ is $\sigma^2$, then the variance of $Y_n$ is $\sigma_{Y_n}^2 = n\sigma^2$. But all the probability inequalities I know of upper-bound tail-probabilities, they don't lower bound them. E.g. [Chebyshev's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) inequality would be an upper-bound on the tail probability $P(|Y_n| > t)$. I know the [second moment method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_moment_method) is a thing, but it doesn't work in this case.

How might I approach this problem?

Comment: You can apply Chebyshev's inequality to the sums of the absolute values.  You just need that E(|X|) > 0 and $\sigma >0$, which is true unless X is deterministically zero (in which case the theorem fails).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symmetry and continuous density are not necessary to conclude. [It is known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2661217/computing-p-limsup-s-n-infty-and-p-liminf-s-n-infty-for-a-random-walk) (but also in [Durrett](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Probability-Cambridge-Statistical-Probabilistic-Mathematics/dp/0521765390), as exercises) that if $Y_n=\sum_{k\leq n}X_k$ is a random walk (i.e. sum of IID $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$) s.t. $E[X_1]=0$ and $P(X_1=0)<1$ (i.e. nondegenerate), then $-\infty = \liminf_{n\to \infty}Y_n< \limsup_{n\to \infty}Y_n =\infty$ a.s.